# Outlook Web Add-In > Extensionpoint for Mail and Calendar home

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I would like to Add a button in the default view under the mail and calendar tabs in Outlook/OWA. The button is well displayed using the extensionpoints so far but they depend on the context (MessageReadCommandSurface, AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface). If no mail is selected or when not in new appointment creation, buttons are not displayed.
I looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint#extension-points-for-outlook) but I do not find how. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of where you are trying to add this add-in button?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to display the button in main Outlook ribbon: https://www.officetooltips.com/images/tips/191_2016/4.png or eventually under the new item in owa like "new Skype meeting"

Comment: What is your intent? Do you want to show a button all of the time? That is not possible with the platform, but you are able to show the button in message & appointment for both read & compose. In that case you need to have all endpoints listed in your manifest.

Comment: The intend is to show a button in the main Outlook menu which is displayed when no mail is selected. The button is used to initiate a new action (e.g. create a custom email or appointment item with pre populated text). You can compare it with the Skype button.